# pdo GROUP BY query not returning all values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website where users can bid other people's stuff (think eBay). Now I've finished the bidding function and want to give the owner some info about the users who bid, email, phone number etc. But I only want to display it once so that if a user bid's 5 times the owner doesn't see this users info 5 times.

I'm using the `GROUP BY` function but this only returns me 2 values but it should return 4 values.

This is the query i'm using:

```
$infoBiederStmt = $objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden GROUP BY ownerid = :ownerid ORDER BY prijs DESC');
```

As far as I know there is nothing wrong with this query. If someone can help me out with this thanks in advance!

Comment: $infoBiederStmt = $objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden ORDER BY prijs DESC GROUP BY ownerid');

Comment: @Anant this query gives me a syntax error. I've fixed it already :) the ORDER BY should be after ownerid. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind giving us the table structure? (just the few fields needed on the bieden table)

Comment: @Anant Yes I've got the answer, thanks again!

Comment: @Anant I did up-vote your answer but I cant mark a comment as answered.

Comment: @Anant Sorry didn't see your answer. I marked it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding to `GROUP BY` is not correct, do like below:-

```
$infoBiederStmt = $objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden GROUP BY ownerid ORDER BY prijs DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you bind value to group by ?

```
$infoBiederStmt = 
$objDatabaseAds->prepare(
     'SELECT * FROM bieden GROUP BY ownerid ORDER BY prijs DESC '
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need correct SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE ownerid = :ownerid GROUP BY bidderid
```